# How create app to app communication in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem, because I can send data from program for example program1 to program2. 
I see that can use events, observer but the problem is how.

Sorry but I not have any code.

Can anybody take here example or link for help to understand events and observers?

Comment: Events and observers have nothing to do with interprocess communication. Interprocess communication is provided by the OS itself and there are *many* ways to do it, simply because there are many different use cases. The *clipboard* is itself an IPC mechanism. Shared memory through mapped files is another. COM allows one application to *control* another. Network-based technologies range from sockets all the way to web services. And then there are mechanisms even on top of HTTP like SignalR, gRPC

Comment: What do you want to actually do? What is the actual use case, what kind of data do you want to send, how often? HTTP is *very* verbose while sockets can send tiny packets for example. Is there any chance that the applications will run on different machines? What are the *security* requirements? For obvious security reasons the OS doesn't allow just any application open a port and listen eg .... to a remote malware controller

Comment: Or perhaps you can just redirect the output of one application to another? That's a communication mechanism too, even though it's one-way

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The Program1 wait for inputs(activated startWorkCommand+input parameters) that send Program2 and when Program1 receive inputs start working. 

After end first of n processes send the created object to Program2 and continue on work. When reach n-th process send that all work was done and Program2 create json with this objects. 

This is that I mean. Sorry for my English :<

Comment: That doesn't explain much. You could just use Process.Start to start the other program, write out the data to its StandardInput stream and read any results from its StandardOutput stream. I believe you can do that just with a Powershell script too. Or you may need a more sophisticated mechanism - what you describe is simply too vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me quickly refer you to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications). This may or may not be exactly what you need, but it should point you in the right direction.

The linked docs list the following options:

- Clipboard
- COM
- Data Copy
- DDE
- File Mapping
- Mailslots
- Pipes
- RPC
- Windows Sockets

There are many articles/guides on how to implement each of those options, so all you really have to do is to Google.

There are also obviously many other options, such as sending data over HTTP or any other easy-to-setup-and-use communications protocol already implemented in .NET (which is presumably what you are using).